# Defer script for pagespeed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to reduce pagespeed, so have tried 'defer attribution' in both external Javascripts. However, when I use defer attribution, my video clip, for my main web-site, disappears.

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="author" content="SemiColonWeb" />
<!-- Stylesheets
============================================= -->
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/jejugothic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-icons.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- External JavaScripts
============================================= -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>

<!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x SCRIPTS  -->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="include/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="include/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js" defer></script>

<!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x CSS SETTINGS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen"/>

<!-- Document Title
============================================= -->
<title>title</title>

<style>

    .revo-slider-emphasis-text {
        font-size: 64px;
        font-weight: 700;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        padding: 15px 20px;
        border-top: 2px solid #FFF;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
    }

    .revo-slider-desc-text {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        width: 650px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    .revo-slider-caps-text {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }

 </style>

</head>

<body class="stretched">

<!-- Document Wrapper
============================================= -->
<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">

    <!-- Header
    ============================================= -->
    <header id="header" class="transparent-header full-header" data-sticky-class="not-dark">


        <div id="header-wrap">

            <div class="container clearfix">

                <div id="primary-menu-trigger"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>

                <!-- Logo
                ============================================= -->
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.html" class="standard-logo" data-dark-logo="images/Logo.png"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                    <a href="index.html" class="retina-logo" data-dark-logo="images/Logo2.png"><img src="images/Logo2.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                </div><!-- #logo end -->

                <!-- Primary Navigation
                ============================================= -->
                <nav id="primary-menu">

                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><div>HOME</div></a></li>    

                        <li><a href="home-greeting.html"><div>Welcome</div></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="home-greeting.html"><div>Greeting</div></a></li>                                         
                                <li><a href="home-about.html"><div>About us</div></a></li>                                     
                                <li><a href="home-staff.html"><div>Staff</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="feature-contact.html"><div>Contact Us</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="home-news.html"><div>News</div></a></li>                                     
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="timeAndPlace.html"><div>Service</div></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="timeAndPlace.html"><div>Time</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="galilee-calendar.html"><div>Calendar</div></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>


                        <li><a href="media-video.html"><div>Media</div></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="media-video.html"><div><i class="icon-play"></i>Video</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="media-galleries.html"><div><i class="icon-picture"></i>Gallery</div></a></li>
                            </ul>



                        </li>
                        <li><a href="ministries-prayer.html"><div>Ministries</div></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="ministries-prayer.html"><div>Pray</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="ministries-local-missions.html"><div>Local Mission</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="ministries-global-missions.html"><div>Global Mission</div></a></li>
                                <li><a href="ministries-outdoors.html"><div>Outdoors</div></a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>

                    </ul>


                </nav><!-- #primary-menu end -->

            </div>

        </div>

    </header><!-- #header end -->

    <section id="slider" class="slider-parallax revoslider-wrap clearfix">

        <!--
        #################################
            - THEMEPUNCH BANNER -
        #################################
        -->
        <div class="tp-banner-container">
            <div class="tp-banner" >
                <ul>    <!-- SLIDE  -->
                    <li class="dark" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="1" data-masterspeed="1000" data-thumb="images/slider/rev/main/s1-thumb.jpg"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Welcome to Galilee">
                        <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->

                        <!-- LAYERS -->

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption tp-fade fadeout fullscreenvideo"
                            data-x="0"
                            data-y="0"
                            data-speed="1000"
                            data-start="1100"
                            data-easing="Power4.easeOut"
                            data-elementdelay="0.01"
                            data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                            data-endspeed="1500"
                            data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn"
                            data-autoplay="true"
                            data-autoplayonlyfirsttime="false"
                            data-nextslideatend="true" 
                            data-volume="mute" data-forceCover="1" data-aspectratio="16:9" data-forcerewind="on" style="z-index: 2;"><video class="" preload="none" width="100%" height="100%">
                        <source src='images/videos/greeting.mp4' type='video/mp4' /></video>

                        </div>

                        <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption customin ltl tp-resizeme revo-slider-caps-text uppercase"
                        data-x="350"
                        data-y="280"
                        data-customin="x:0;y:150;z:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;"
                        data-speed="800"
                        data-start="1000"
                        data-easing="easeOutQuad"
                        data-splitin="none"
                        data-splitout="none"
                        data-elementdelay="0.01"
                        data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                        data-endspeed="1000"
                        data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 3;">This is</div>

                        <div class="tp-caption customin ltl tp-resizeme revo-slider-emphasis-text nopadding noborder"
                        data-x="270"
                        data-y="300"
                        data-customin="x:0;y:150;z:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;"
                        data-speed="800"
                        data-start="1200"
                        data-easing="easeOutQuad"
                        data-splitin="none"
                        data-splitout="none"
                        data-elementdelay="0.01"
                        data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                        data-endspeed="1000"
                        data-endeasing="Power4.easeIn" style="z-index: 3;">Welcome</div>                                                
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var tpj=jQuery;
            tpj.noConflict();

            tpj(document).ready(function() {

                var apiRevoSlider = tpj('.tp-banner').show().revolution(
                {
                    dottedOverlay:"none",
                    delay:9000,
                    startwidth:1140,
                    startheight:700,
                    hideThumbs:200,

                    thumbWidth:100,
                    thumbHeight:50,
                    thumbAmount:3,

                    navigationType:"none",
                    navigationArrows:"solo",
                    navigationStyle:"preview4",

                    touchenabled:"on",
                    onHoverStop:"on",

                    swipe_velocity: 0.7,
                    swipe_min_touches: 1,
                    swipe_max_touches: 1,
                    drag_block_vertical: false,


                    parallax:"mouse",
                    parallaxBgFreeze:"on",
                    parallaxLevels:[8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],
                    parallaxDisableOnMobile:"on",


                    keyboardNavigation:"on",

                    navigationHAlign:"center",
                    navigationVAlign:"bottom",
                    navigationHOffset:0,
                    navigationVOffset:20,

                    soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
                    soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
                    soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
                    soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

                    soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
                    soloArrowRightValign:"center",
                    soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
                    soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

                    shadow:0,
                    fullWidth:"off",
                    fullScreen:"on",

                    spinner:"spinner0",

                    stopLoop:"off",
                    stopAfterLoops:-1,
                    stopAtSlide:-1,

                    shuffle:"off",


                    forceFullWidth:"off",
                    fullScreenAlignForce:"off",
                    minFullScreenHeight:"400",

                    hideThumbsOnMobile:"off",
                    hideNavDelayOnMobile:1500,
                    hideBulletsOnMobile:"off",
                    hideArrowsOnMobile:"off",
                    hideThumbsUnderResolution:0,

                    hideSliderAtLimit:0,
                    hideCaptionAtLimit:0,
                    hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,
                    startWithSlide:0,
                    fullScreenOffsetContainer: ".header"
                });

                apiRevoSlider.bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
                    if( $(window).width() > 992 ) {
                        if( $('#slider ul > li').eq(data.slideIndex-1).hasClass('dark') ){
                            $('#header.transparent-header:not(.sticky-header,.semi-transparent)').addClass('dark');
                            $('#header.transparent-header.sticky-header,#header.transparent-header.semi-transparent.sticky-header').removeClass('dark');
                            $('#header-wrap').removeClass('not-dark');
                        } else {
                            if( $('body').hasClass('dark') ) {
                                $('#header.transparent-header:not(.semi-transparent)').removeClass('dark');
                                $('#header.transparent-header:not(.sticky-header,.semi-transparent)').find('#header-wrap').addClass('not-dark');
                            } else {
                                $('#header.transparent-header:not(.semi-transparent)').removeClass('dark');
                                $('#header-wrap').removeClass('not-dark');
                            }
                        }
                        SEMICOLON.header.darkLogo();
                    }
                });

            }); //ready

        </script>


        <!-- END REVOLUTION SLIDER -->

    </section>

    <!-- Content
    ============================================= -->
    <section id="content">

        <div class="content-wrap">

            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="row clearfix">

                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <div class="heading-block topmargin">
                            <h1>Welcome</h1>
                        </div>
                        <p class="lead">Welcoming!!</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-7">

                        <div style="position: relative; margin-top: 60px;" class="ohidden" data-height-lg="426" data-height-md="567" data-height-sm="470" data-height-xs="287" data-height-xxs="183">
                            <img src="images/portfolio/welcome.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay="100" alt="Chrome">

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(window).load(function(){

                    var $container = $('#portfolio');

                    $container.isotope({
                        transitionDuration: '0.65s',
                        masonry: {
                            columnWidth: $container.find('.portfolio-item:not(.wide)')[0]
                        }
                    });

                    $('#page-menu a').click(function(){
                        $('#page-menu li').removeClass('current');
                        $(this).parent('li').addClass('current');
                        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
                        return false;
                    });

                    $(window).resize(function() {
                        $container.isotope('layout');
                    });

                });

            </script>

        </div>

    </section><!-- #content end -->



        <!-- Copyrights
        ============================================= -->
        <div id="copyrights">

            <div class="container clearfix">

                <div class="col_half">
                    ⓒ 2014 godlovesjoe<br>

                </div>

                <div class="col_half col_last tright">
                    <div class="fright clearfix">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com" class="social-icon si-small si-borderless si-facebook">
                            <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
                            <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
                        </a>

                        <a href="http://www.webpage.com/" class="social-icon si-small si-borderless si-globe">
                            <i class="icon-globe"></i>
                            <i class="icon-globe"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>

                    <i class="icon-envelope2"></i> email-address@hotmail.com <span class="middot">&middot;</span> <i class="icon-phone-sign"></i> (+1)604-657-3937<span class="middot">&middot;</span> 
                </div>

            </div>

        </div><!-- #copyrights end -->

    </footer><!-- #footer end -->

</div><!-- #wrapper end -->

<!-- Go To Top
============================================= -->
<div id="gotoTop" class="icon-angle-up"></div>

<!-- Footer Scripts
============================================= -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js" defer></script> // i tried this code

Comment: Not all scripts should and can be deferred.

Comment: so there is no way to reduce my page by editing my external scripts?

Comment: Reduce the page by editing external scripts, sure, edit away. For scripts needed during initial parsing of the page, they shouldn't be defered.

Comment: You can hide the video initially and then once js loads and is ready, show it.

Comment: when I using gtmetrix for checking my pagespeed, i got this msg "Defer parsing of JavaScript F (25) 60% JS High
What does this mean?
427.9KiB of JavaScript is parsed during initial page load. Defer parsing JavaScript to reduce blocking of page rendering.

http://mywebpage.com/js/plugins.js (339.9KiB)
http://mywebpag/js/jquery.js (86.2KiB)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way defer works is that it loads asynchronously. It should only be used for JS scripts that do not depend on each other.

i.e. for loading `jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js`, you need to have jquery loaded, so `jquery` cannot be deferred. For calling `var apiRevoSlider = tpj('.tp-banner').show().revolution` you need to have the `include/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js` file loaded, so you cannot defer it.

In order to increase the page speed of your site I suggest you the following:

1. You should compile all the CSS files into one file instead of having 10 different files. You can Grunt or Gulp and they'll do the work for you. Also, you can use a tool online like: https://csscompressor.net/.
2. Google fonts. Do you really need all those family fonts / weights?
   `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic`. Try removing all the ones you don’t really need.
3. All the JS should be at the bottom of the page. Move the following scripts to the very bottom of the page (right before the `body` close tag).

Try this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.js"><\/script>')</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="include/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="include/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
```

After that, you can have the inline scripts:

```
<script>
    var tpj=jQuery;
    tpj.noConflict();
    ...

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        var $container = $('#portfolio');

        $container.isotope({
            transitionDuration: '0.65s',
    ....
</script>
```

This should be the last script (this can keep the defer attribute)
`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js" defer></script>`

With only that your page speed will increase a lot. The problem with having the JS at the head, is that it will block the rendering of the page until it finishes loading.

If you want to keep optimizing the page, it will get tricker. You will need to use a JS compiler with dependency control. I recommend [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) even though the setup is kind of complex. There are tools out there that can help with the setup ([Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) / [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/)).

Comment: i'm happy it helped you. maybe you can select my response as the good one! :)